# run command line app and use progress bar to track

Tags: c#, command-line, progress-bar

im making a gui for a console application(we will call it editor) i made and want to run the editor app with arguments then put the editor output into a richtextbox(working partly) i also want to add a progress bar to show how long is left to wait heres the code im using atm

```
    public void LaunchEditor(string arg)
    {
        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "Editor.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.Start();
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + line;
        }
    }
```

also for some reason its not displaying the full output in the rich text box can anyone help with both or either of these problems thanks

Comment: Whats "editor.exe" doing? Does it report progress? If not, a progressbar will be nearly purely guessing, if you cant calculate the esterminated time.

Comment: how would i make editor.exe report progress i coded it in c++(still noob at c++) thanks

Comment: you can have console.write in your exe to return progress status

Comment: im looking into sending the progress can anyone help on the other prob im having

Comment: There are many ways to report progress, you have to pick one.Named Pipes, WCF, MSMQ, a Database... But for your project it seems like to break a butterfly on a wheel. Maybe dont hide editor.exe and report progress in its console window (as Patel suggested) instead? To fix your outputproblem try StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), i guess your appliation returns then ONE line

Comment: @pengu tried that didnt work same result outputting first 3 lines then nothing

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe to the OutputDataReceived event of your process

```
process.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived; //YOUR EVENT HANDLER HERE;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

and process the data received from your exe in your event handler delegate

```
void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       //PROGRESS BAR HERE
//ACCESS DATA SENT BY EXE IN e
string data = e.Data.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: trying now will post results

Comment: you need to call waitforexit method of your process after process.Start()